# Sql get multiple same row

Tags: php, mysql

**`$uid is 6`**

```
    public function getUserGroups($uid) {
    $sql = "SELECT groups.id, groups.name, groups.type , groups.img_path, DATE_FORMAT(user_group.joined_at,'%e/%c/%Y %H:%i') joined_at FROM groups JOIN user_group ON groups.id = user_group.group_id WHERE groups.id IN (SELECT group_id FROM user_group WHERE user_id = ?)";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array($uid));
    if($query->rowCount()) {
        $user_groups = $query->fetchAll();
        return $user_groups;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function bring true data from tables but multiple times. 
Here the outputs :

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Test Grubu' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Test Grubu' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'AÃ§Ä±k Grup' (length=11)
      2 => string 'AÃ§Ä±k Grup' (length=11)
      'img_path' => string 'images/groupimages/11-09-2015-12-48-56_ic_participation_off.png' (length=63)
      3 => string 'images/groupimages/11-09-2015-12-48-56_ic_participation_off.png' (length=63)
      'joined_at' => string '9/11/2015 00:48' (length=15)
      4 => string '9/11/2015 00:48' (length=15)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '4' (length=1)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'Test Grubu' (length=10)
      1 => string 'Test Grubu' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'AÃ§Ä±k Grup' (length=11)
      2 => string 'AÃ§Ä±k Grup' (length=11)
      'img_path' => string 'images/groupimages/11-09-2015-12-48-56_ic_participation_off.png' (length=63)
      3 => string 'images/groupimages/11-09-2015-12-48-56_ic_participation_off.png' (length=63)
      'joined_at' => string '9/11/2015 11:50' (length=15)
      4 => string '9/11/2015 11:50' (length=15)
```

user_group :

[image: Group]

groups :

[image]

I want to get user' s all group. I save to user_group, and all groups keeping in groups.

Comment: Can you develop the question please ?

Comment: what you mean by **get multiple same row**?? Your  question is like (**ans*2**)

Comment: return same row two-times

Comment: Use SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: you should use `group by groups.id` at the end , as it will only get you the result grouped by the id you asked for , and not multiple time ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I true understand your question, I think something like that:

```sql
SELECT
  groups.id,
  groups.name,
  groups.type,
  groups.img_path,
  DATE_FORMAT(user_group.joined_at, '%e/%c/%Y %H:%i') joined_at
FROM groups
  JOIN user_group ON groups.id = user_group.group_id
WHERE groups.id IN (SELECT group_id
                    FROM user_group
                    WHERE user_id = ?)
GROUP BY groups.id;
```